# Spring AOP: Aspect not working on called method

Tags: java, spring, aop

This is my first time with AOP so this might be very noob question.

```
public class MyAspect implements AspectI {

public void method1() throws AsyncApiException {
    System.out.println("In Method1. calling method 2");
    method2();
}

@RetryOnInvalidSessionId
public void method2() throws AsyncApiException {
    System.out.println("In Method2, throwing exception");
    throw new AsyncApiException("method2", AsyncExceptionCode.InvalidSessionId);
}

public void login() {
    System.out.println("Logging");
}
```

InvalidSessionHandler looks like this.

```
@Aspect
public class InvalidSessionIdHandler implements Ordered {

    @Around("@annotation(com.pkg.RetryOnInvalidSessionId)")
    public void reLoginAll(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Hijacked call: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " Proceeding");
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (e instanceof AsyncApiException) {
                AsyncApiException ae = (AsyncApiException) e;
                if (ae.getExceptionCode() == AsyncExceptionCode.InvalidSessionId) {
                    System.out.println("invalid session id. relogin");
                    AspectI myAspect = (AspectI) joinPoint.getTarget();
                    myAspect.login();
                    System.out.println("Login done. Proceeding again now");
                    joinPoint.proceed();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Spring configuration

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="myAspect" class="com.pkg.MyAspect" />
<bean id="invalidSessionIdHandler" class="com.pkg.InvalidSessionIdHandler" />
```

1. My intent is when I call `myAspect.method1()` which in turns calls `method2`, if `method2` throws `InvalidSessionId` Exception, then only `method2` should be retried. But above code does not seem to do anything. It just immediately returns after exception is thrown from method2. However if I put `@RetryOnInvalidSessionId` on `method1` then whole `method1` is retried.
2. For learning I kept `method2` is public but in actual I want it to be `private`. I am out of clue here, how to retry private method.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with your current setup. With Spring's AOP features, your class `InvalidSessionIdHandler` will get created as a bean and then scanned for annotations/method signatures/etc. relevant to your `MyAspect` class. It will find `method2()` and therefore create a proxy wrapping the bean it's already created. The proxy will have the behavior from your advice.

Spring will the inject this (proxy) bean where you need it. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
   @Autowired
   private MyAspect aspect;

   public void callMethod2() {
       aspect.method2();
   }
}
```

In this case, the `MyClass` object has a reference to the proxy. When it calls `aspect.method2()`, the added behavior will be executed.

In your code, however, you're expecting to call `method2()` within `method1()`

```
public void method1() throws AsyncApiException {
    System.out.println("In Method1. calling method 2");
    method2();
}
```

which is within your `MyAspect` class. Technically, what is happening here is `method2()` getting called on `this` as `this.method2()`. `this` is a reference to the actual object, not the proxy. It will therefore not execute any additional behavior.

The [AOP Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) explains this in more detail.

The workaround here is to refactor so that `method2()` is in another class/object or to call it from outside, ie. not from `method1()`.

Comment: This is correct. Note that, by default, `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` will create JDK proxies (interface-based only) for beans/components wrapped in AOP. To introduce AOP behavior for methods not defined by an interface, you have to use `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`, but even so, you will have to call the method on the proxy to leverage the AOP behavior. Calling `this.someMethod()` inside the proxied class will not leverage AOP because, as @Sotirios describes, `this` references the target instance, not the proxy.

Comment: Is it possible with any other set up other than refactoring out method2 in different class? I mean I can always refactor it but method2 logically belongs to current class only. It's even private method.

Comment: I think, you can have a `@Component` annotated private inner class with only that method. And `@Autowired` a private field to call the method on.

Comment: I tried creating inner private class MyAspectUtil as you mentioned but it fails with error 'No visible constructors in class com.pkg.MyAspect.MyAspectUtil